# simple bind failed: host:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]

Tags: active-directory

When I am trying to login to my application, I am getting an error

> Exception searching Directory : javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ip address:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]

I have already imported the certificate from the machine where AD is installed. Also, no computer names are coming in the Administrative Console of AD.

Comment: Here are a few things to check: 1) Can you connect to AD on port 389 (non SSL port? 2) Is the bind id and passowd correct? 3) Are you able to connect to AD from ldapsearch command? 4) Is there any FFDC generated to indicate more specific problem?

Comment: Please remember that when you transfer a technical problem to a volunteer-driven site like Stack Overflow, it does not become urgent for anyone else. Your question has the same priority as all the other ones that came in today.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: [Contact Active Directory with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797859/contact-active-directory-with-ssl/35820983#35820983)

I think the same things apply here. At least it's a good starting point.