# Upgarding java from 1.8_131 to 1.8_361 is causing the dcldap error

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate

After upgrading the java version from 1.8_131 to 1.8_361, I re-imported the previously used certs(with java 1.8_131) but the authentication is failing with the error
"Your login attempt was not successful, try again.  Caused : simple bind failed: dcldap:636"

I came across the below links and link(2) is for java documentation for the version 1.8_181 where there were changes to LDAP Support.
The link(4) talks about how to disable the endpoint identification introduced in java 1.8_181.

My Question is,

- How to resolve the issue without disabling the endpoint identification? do i need a new set of certificates or some setting changes?
- Is it recommended and safe to disable the endpoint identification discussed in link(4) ?

Any help is appreciated.

(1)[Java upgrade 8 to 11 causing issue with LDAPS connection (Connection or outbound has closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911874/java-upgrade-8-to-11-causing-issue-with-ldaps-connection-connection-or-outbound)
(2) https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u181-relnotes.html
(3)[simple bind failed: host:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864165/simple-bind-failed-host636-root-exception-is-java-net-socketexception-connec)
(4) [How to disable endpoint identification for java 1.8.181 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449801/how-to-disable-endpoint-identification-for-java-1-8-181-version)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i disabled the endpoint identificaiton by passing the below VM argument in eclipse and that fixed the dcldap error.

-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true